# `npm` dependency from Git repository not build properly when installed by `yarn`

Tags: node.js, git, npm, yarnpkg

I have repository `shared-code` on my Git.
This is structure of my package:

```
shared-code
|- package.json
|- tsconfig.json
|- src/
|-- index.ts
|-- foo.ts
|-- bar.ts
|- lib/ <-- automatically created when tsc build
```

This is `package.json` of this npm package:

```
{
  "name": "shared-code",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc --watch",
    "prepare": "npm run build"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "types": "lib/index.d.ts",
  "devDependencies":{
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4"
  }
}
```

when I want to include this package into another project I do so by adding it to `package.json`:

```
...
"dependencies": {
  "shared-code": "git+https://<username>@bitbucket.org/foo/shared-code.git"
}
...
```

Then I run `npm install` and `shared-code` package is successfully installed and TypeScript is built.

But, when I install it by `yarn install` package is installed and just one file is built (`/lib/index.js`). Other files are not transcribed as supposted.

Where is problem? Is this `yarn` bug? Or `yarn` works differently?